# created json dynamically but how to prevent from ampersand(&) and backslash(\)

Tags: php, json

i have a little problem in my jquery php chat using json, data is dynamically generating but my chat code won't work if a user hit \& or & or \ any suggestion
php code

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{      "items": [ <?php echo $items;?> ]}
<?
```

this wont work

```
{

        "s": "0",
        "n":"Praveen Jain",
        "f": "100025",
        "m": "\&amp;"
       },
```

this work:

{

```
    "s": "0",
    "n":"Praveen Jain",
"f": "100025",
    "m": "\\&amp;"
   },
```

is there any help... i know json forbid '\' and '&' these two character

js code for processing json

```
function startChatSession(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "hsdrt/chkat.php?action=startchatsession",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        username = data.username;
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            if (item)   { // fix strange ie bug
            chatboxid = item.n;
                        chatboxtitle = item.f;
                    if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).length <= 0)
                                                   {createChatBox(chatboxtitle,chatboxid,1);}

                if (item.s == 1) 
                                           {item.n = username;}

                if (item.s == 2) 
                                          {
   $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxinfo">'+item.m+'</span></div>');  


   }
   else {
$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.n+'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+item.m+'</span></div>');

                }
            }
        });

    for (i=0;i<chatBoxes.length;i++) {
            chatboxtitle = chatBoxes[i];
    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
    setTimeout('$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);', 100); // yet another strange ie bug
        }
    setTimeout('chatHeartbeat();',chatHeartbeatTime);
    }

    });
}
```

Comment: if you know these two are only character which creating problem then before creating json data you can change them using `str_replace` function in php

Comment: i tried, but not working str_replace('\&','\\&',$items);

Comment: try this code `function convertSpecialChars($string){
        $string = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $string);
        $string = str_replace('/', '//;', $string);
        return $string;
    }` and add what ever string you want to modify in the same way

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use json_encode? https://www.php.net/json_encode
It takes care all the escaping for you, so all you worry is just to structure your data correctly :)

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

-- EDIT --

Structure your data in php, and let json_encode encodes it, like so:

```
$userdata = array(
   'uid': $uid, 'username': $firstname, 'items': $items
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($userdata);
```

Comment: actual code is something like that i dont know how to change that{       "uid": "<?php echo $uid; ?>",
   "username": "<?php echo $firstname; ?>",
      "items": [ <?php echo $items;?> ]
}

Comment: not working ajax response is {"uid":"100045","username":"Neha Swar","items":"\t\t\t\t\t   {\r\n\t\t\t\"s\": \"1\",\r\n\t\t\t\"f\": \"100020\",\r\n\t\t\t\"n\": \"Vivek Chandra\",\r\n\t\t\t\"m\": \"hi\"\r\n\t   },\t\t\t\t\t}]}

Comment: What javascript method do you use to parse the json returned?

Comment: Please post the javascript code you used to get the ajax response

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode()
http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Take a look at the second (options) parameter for encoding...

```
echo json_encode($value,
    JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT |
    JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

In PHP 5.4 you can use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT...

Comment: i tried JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, JSON_HEX_QUOT none of them worked still the same result